# return a view to ajax request

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5.4

I am using Laravel 54 .I am trying to display a form using an ajax request.
I return a json response but the received data in java-script is a string that contains two objects!!

my action

```
public function edit($product)
    {
        $product = Product::where(['id'=>$product])->get();
        $categories=Category::orderBy('name')->get();
        var_dump($categories);
        $view=view('product.manage',compact('categories','product'));
        $html=$view->render();
        return response()->json(['success'=>true,'html'=>$html]);
    }
```

java-script code

```
$(document).on('click','.edit-product',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var url=$(this).attr('href');
    $.ajax({
        url:url,
        type:'get',
        success:function(response){
            $('#data-holder').html(response.html);
        },
        error:function(e){
            alert(e);
        }
    });
```

response variable in java-script is:

```
"object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#212 (1) {
  ["items":protected]=>
  array(8) {
    [0]=>
    object(App\Category)#213 (24) {
      ["connection":protected]=>
      string(5) "mysql"
      ["table":protected]=>
      NULL
      ["primaryKey":protected]=>
      string(2) "id"
      ["keyType":protected]=>
      string(3) "int"
      ["incrementing"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["with":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["perPage":protected]=>
      int(15)
      ["exists"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["wasRecentlyCreated"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["attributes":protected]=>
      array(2) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(5)
        ["name"]=>
        string(15) "Beauty & Health"
        //................................
      }
    }
  }
}
{"success":true,"html":"<div class=\"container\">\n    <div class=\"row\">\n    //...........    \n    <\/div>\n<\/div>"}"
```

How can I access the returned view html?

Comment: `var_dump($categories);` ? :)

Answer (score 0):

Delete `var_dump($categories);` part, because that part prints the Object's content.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel by default rendering of the partial. You are calling `View::make()` and returning the rendered view to `$html`.